# How does GitHub.com produce it's diff views?

Tags: javascript, github, diff

I really like the diff views on GitHub.com. I was hoping to use the same module(s) they use on my website for diffing small json objects in the same beautiful and readable way, but I can't find the source code for GitHub.com, which I believe is close sourced...

Does anyone know how they achieve this result? Which modules they use, for example? Or are there any components out there that clone the GitHub.com diff views?

I'm looking for a module that can help me transform `before` and `after` blobs of json into a visual diff like you would see on GitHub.com when looking at a commit. My own solutions shows removed characters in red and added characters in green, but GitHub.com's solution is much more elegant, showing the full lines with a red or green background, but also with the specific characters added or removed sporting a darker background color. I don't need any of the interactivity or line numbers of anything.

**Notes:**

- I looked at gitlab.com, which features a very similar diff view and is fully open source, but if I understand correctly, they produce the diff views on the server side, which is not an option for me at the moment.
- I also found https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-diff and modules like that, but I find the result less readable than what I see on GitHub.com.
- I am now using https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff to power a custom component that just uses `<ins>` and `<del>` to show what was added/removed. This doesn't produce a result anywhere as good as what GitHub.com has, but before spending hours on iteratively improving my custom component, I wanted to make I hadn't simply missed an existing component out there that reproduce the GitHub.com look, hence this question.
- I am open to react components, jquery solutions, or anything else. I use react myself, but if I find what I need written for JQuery for example, I should be able to "translate" it. I'm mostly looking for either a react component doing exactly what I want (GitHub.com-style diff view) or something in another framework that can serve as inspiration to get my custom component up to par.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too broad... and probably that's why this question is going to be closed, but maybe you are looking into something like [highlightjs](/questions/tagged/highlightjs). Js code example:

```
  var c = document.createElement("code");
  c.className = "code blink hljs diff";
  c.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(varWithYourDiffCode, null, "\t");
  hljs.highlightBlock(c);
  document.getElementById("root").appendChild(c);
```

Comment: What is this hljs thing? The npm module with that name (http://npmjs.com/package/hljs) has no readme and the linked github repo returns a 404. Is that the one you're talking about?

Comment: Here link https://highlightjs.org/usage/

Comment: I can see on the demo page (https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/) that this looks nothing like the GitHub.com diffs... I will try to edit my question, apparently I am not getting my message across correctly. Doesn't feel too broad to me at all..

Comment: Sure, I've tried to help but failed, sorry...

Comment: haha no it's very much appreciated, just not what I'm looking for

Comment: I modified my question a bit, I hope it feels less broad now..

Comment: I'd decided that you're looking for code highlight... but it seems that you're looking for interactive highlighted interface, am I right?

Comment: I'm looking for a module that can help me transform `before` and `after` blobs of json into a visual diff like you would see on GitHub.com when looking at a commit. My own solutions shows removed characters in red and added characters in green, but GitHub.com's solution is much more elegant, showing the full lines with a red or green background, but also with the specific characters added or removed sporting a darker background color. I don't need any of the interactivity or line numbers of anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking into structure of `diff` file, for example command:

```
git diff myFile.md
```

will generate:

```
-* AVL tree - the **heights of the two child subtrees of any node differ by at most one**.
+* AVL tree - (since 1962) the **heights of the two child subtrees of any node differ by at most one**.
```

but command:

```
git diff --word-diff myFile.md
```

will generate:

```
* AVL tree - {+(since 1962)+} the **heights of the two child subtrees of any node differ by at most one**.
```

Screen from my terminal:

[image]

Comment: GitHub.com seems to use a mix of these two techniques where you not only see the before and after lines, but within these lines, the additions and removals are also highlighted. As an example, notice the port change in the following diff: https://github.com/cn007b/my/commit/b7926bc0e4ae91d29ace9563f12dd52b858f378b#diff-23b6f443c01ea2efcb4f36eedfea9089

Comment: Yes! And they definitely use `--word-diff`.

Comment: Is it right direction of understanding your question?)

Comment: Let me try to rephrase. The perfect answer to my question would be a link the the part of the GitHub.com source code that produces the diff views. Of course if the source code is not accessible, I will never get such an answer. Also acceptable would be an answer that points me to a module that can transform the output you provide in this answer into the html diff view we can see on GitHub.com. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Is diff2html the kind of thing you're looking for: https://diff2html.xyz/?

It's a javascript component you can integrate into an existing page.  They give examples of angular and raw HTML usage here: https://github.com/rtfpessoa/diff2html#how-to-use